# phpMyAdmin Errors are not being Displayed

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am using phpMyAdmin but when I enter a query that is invalid, it doesn't give me an error. Instead, it does nothing.

For example, when I enter an invalid query and click "submit query":
[image]

The only way I know there is an error is by checking the requests I'm sending. But no error message pops up...
[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: if you have two columns, you need to specify two values

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue is from the server setting.

Open you phpMyAdmin and locate your server [server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tZLA.png)

Then click on settings and locate SQL queries [settings & sql queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VIvy.png)

Locate **Ignore multiple statement errors**, and this should be checked currently on your system. [multiple statement errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2J0p.png)

Uncheck it and click on apply, then reload your query box.